# Automating SQL scripts run into AWS redshift environments (Dev, preprod & prod)

Tags: automation, amazon-redshift, aws-codepipeline

I wish to automate runs of SQL (DML's and DML's) into the AWS redshift cluster, i.e. as soon as someone merge the SQL file into S3 bucket it should run in the configured environment say dev, preprod & prod.
Is there any way I can do this?

My investigation says that AWS codepipeline is one of the solution however, I am not sure how I will connect to the Redshift database in Codepipeline?

Another way is using Lambda function but it has its limitation of 5 minutes I guess and some of the DDL/DML might take more than 5 minutes to run.

Regards,
Shay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of choices out there and which is best will depend on many factors including your team's skillset and your budget.  I'll let the community weigh in on all the possibilities.

I would like to advise on using the AWS serverless ecosystem to perform these functions.  First off the Lambda limit is now 15 min but this really isn't important.  The most important development is Redshift Data API which lets you start queries in a Lambda and for other Lambdas check on completion later.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html

With Redshift Data API for fire-and-forget access to Redshift and Step Functions to orchestrate the Lambda functions you can create a low cost, light weight infrastructure to perform all sort of integrations and actions.  These can include triggering other tools / services as needed for you.  This is not the best approach in all cases but Lambda based solutions should not be excluded due to run time limits.